# How to prevent direct access to my JSON service?

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, json

I have a JSON web service to return home markers to be displayed on my Google Map.

Essentially, `http://example.com` calls the web service to find out the location of all map markers to display like so:

```
http://example.com/json/?zipcode=12345
```

And it returns a JSON string such as:

```
{"address": "321 Main St, Mountain View, CA, USA", ...}
```

So on my `index.html` page, I take that JSON string and place the map markers.

However, what I don't want to have happen is people calling out to my JSON web service **directly**.

I only want `http://example.com/index.html` to be able to call my `http://example.com/json/` web service ... and not some random dude calling the `/json/` directly.

**Quesiton**: how do I prevent direct calling/access to my `http://example.com/json/` web service?

---

**UPDATE:**

To give more clarity, `http://example.com/index.html` call `http://example.com/json/?zipcode=12345` ... and the JSON service
- returns semi-sensitive data,
- returns a JSON array,
- responds to GET requests,
- the browser making the request has JavaScript enabled

Again, what I don't want to have happen is people simply look at my `index.html` source code and then call the JSON service directly.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few good ways to authenticate clients.

- By IP address.  In Apache, use the Allow / Deny directives.
- By HTTP auth: basic or digest.  This is nice and standardized, and uses usernames/passwords to authenticate.
- By cookie.  You'll have to come up with the cookie.
- By a custom HTTP header that you invent.

Edit:

I didn't catch at first that your web service is being called by client-side code.  It is literally NOT POSSIBLE to prevent people from calling your web service directly, if you let client-side Javascript do it.  Someone could just read the source code.

Comment: Wouldn't the Allow / Deny *not* work because that would deny everyone to index.html which CALLS the JSON request.

Comment: Dietrich, exactly - people reading my source code is the concern. So no way to prevent?

Comment: Correct, NO way to prevent.  It's like handing someone a set of keys and telling them only to open the door on Thursdays.

Comment: Agreed, no way to prevent. Other threads have discussed this as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561999/how-can-i-validate-secure-authenticate-a-javascript-based-post-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576509/wcf-rest-based-services-authentication-schemes/2576824#2576824

Answer (score 5):

Some more specific answers here, but I'd like to make the following general point:

Anything done over AJAX is being loaded by the user's browser. You could make a hacker's life hard if you wanted to, but, ultimately, **there is no way of stopping me from getting data that you already freely make available to me**. Any service that is publicly available is publicly available, plain and simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache you can set allow/deny on locations.

http://www.apachesecurity.net/

or here is a link to the apache docs on the Deny directive

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#deny

EDITS (responding to the new info).

The Deny directive also works with environment variables. You can restrict access based on browser string (not really secure, but discourages casual browsing) which would still allow XHR calls.

I would suggest the best way to accomplish this is to have a token of some kind that validates the request is a 'good' request.  You can do that with a cookie, a session store of some kind, or a parameter (or some combination).

What I would suggest for something like this is to generate a unique url for the service that expires after a short period of time.  You could do something like this pretty easily with Memcache.  This strategy could also be used to obfuscate the service url (which would not provide any actual security, but would raise the bar for someone wanting to make direct calls).

Lastly, you could also use public key crypto to do this, but that would be *very* heavy.  You would need to generate a new pub/priv key pair for each request and return the pubkey to the js client (here is a link to an implementation in javascript) http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/notes/rsademo/

Comment: When people say "JSON" in the context of a web page they usually mean XHR, which Deny will block if used indiscriminately.

Comment: I believe if I used this method, that would deny EVERYONE access to my web site. ... Meaning, this would NOT WORK

Comment: It would only deny EVERYONE access to your web site if you specified to deny everyone.  You can add deny/allow based on location.

Comment: ... And where exactly will the hackers be coming from, Joshua?

Comment: From his original question (before the edits) it looked to me like he was wanting to restrict access to that service in such a way that only the server could call the service.  He's added edits that clarify and now that interpretation is clearly not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a random number as a flag to determine whether the request are coming from the page just sent:

1) When generates `index.html`, add a random number to the JSON request URL:

Old: `http://example.com/json/?zipcode=12345`

New: `http://example.com/json/?zipcode=12345&f=234234234234234234`

Add this number to the *Session Context* as well.

2) The client browser renders the `index.html` and request JSON data by the new URL.

3) Your server gets the json request and checks the flag number with *Session Context*. If matched, response data. Otherwise, return an error message.

4) Clear *Session Context* by the end of response, or timeout triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Accept only POST requests to the JSON-yielding URL. That won't prevent determined people from getting to it, but it will prevent casual browsing.

Comment: How to I do POST XmlHttpRequest?  I thought you could only do GET requests.

Comment: XmlHttpRequest can do any method, including methods you make up.  The first parameter when you open a request is the method, which is an arbitrary string.

Comment: I use something like jQuery that knows how to POST XHR. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone getting here later this is the easiest way to do this. You need to protect the AJAX subpage with a password that you can set on the container page before calling the include.

The easiest way to do this is to require HTTPS on the AJAX call and pass a POST variable. HTTPS + POST ensures the password is always encrypted.

So on the AJAX/sub-page do something like

```
if ($_POST["access"] == "makeupapassword")
{
  ...
}
else
{
  echo "You can't access this directly";
}
```

When you call the AJAX make sure to include the POST variable and password in your payload. Since it is in POST it will be encrypted, and since it is random (hopefully) nobody will be able to guess it.

If you want to include or require the PHP directly on another page, just set the POST variable to the password before including it.

```
$_POST["access"] = "makeupapassword";
require("path/to/the/ajax/file.php");
```

This is a lot better than maintaining a global variable, session variable, or cookie because some of those are persistent across page loads so you have to make sure to reset the state after checking so users can't get accidental access.

Also I think it is better than page headers because it can't be sniffed since it is secured by HHTPS.

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably have to have some kind of cookie-based authentication.  In addition, Ignacio has a good point about using POST.  This can help prevent [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) if you have untrusted scripts running on your domain.  However, I don't think using POST is strictly necessary unless the outermost JSON type is an array.  In your example it is an object.

Comment: The reason for using POST is not security. It's due to the fact that the default method browsers use when you stuff a URL in the location bar is GET. If GET isn't allowed at the server then they don't see the JSON.

Comment: Ignacio, take a look at my link.  POST can help defeat a particular JSON hijacking attack.

Comment: Sure. But that's not why I suggested it.